# how to write broadcast receiver that monitor income sms and show in Toast

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver

I want to develop an app in which specific income SMSes are monitored for their name and body of text show in toast.
And how to prevent such an SMS from being inserted in the inbox, as we don't need that SMS comes to inbox.

**Receiver Code:**

```
    public class mReciver extends BroadcastReceiver {

     SmsManager sms = SmsManager.getDefault();

     public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

      // there I need code
     }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually data is in intent you can easily get receive number and text from intent
// write code like that

```
public class mReciver extends BroadcastReceiver {
String IncomeNumber,Incometext ;
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
            Bundle bundle = intent.getExtras();

            if (bundle != null) {
                final Object[] pdusObj = (Object[]) bundle.get("pdus");
                for (int i = 0; i < pdusObj.length; i++) {
                    SmsMessage inComeText = SmsMessage
                            .createFromPdu((byte[]) pdusObj[i]);
                    IncomeNumber = inComeText
                            .getDisplayOriginatingAddress();
                    Incometext = inComeText.getDisplayMessageBody();
                }
            }

        }
    }
```

for specific number you just compare number with store number
like that.

```
if(IncomeNumber.equals("+123456788")){
    Toast.makeText(context,"Text: "+Incometext+"\nfrom: "+IncomeNumber, 0).show();
    abortBroadcast();
}
```

and **abortBroadcast();** for prevent form store inbox

Comment: first of all you need to add permission 
    <!-- SMS ! -->
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_SMS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_SMS" />

then 
<receiver android:name=".mReciver" >
            <intent-filter android:priority="1000" >
                <action android:name="android.provider.Telephony.SMS_RECEIVED" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>

Comment: And please don't name your class mReceiver. It should be Receiver if anything. Class names in Java are -by convention- CamelCase; also field names are normally prefixed with an "m" to indicate they are class level field members, so `IncomeNumber` and `Incometext` should be: `mIncomeNumber` and `mIncomeText` respectively.

Answer (score 0):

try something like,

```
 public class SmsReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
 // vars here

 @Override
  public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

    // Get SMS map from Intent
    Bundle extras = intent.getExtras();

    if (extras != null) {
        // Get received SMS array
        Object[] smsExtra = (Object[]) extras.get(SMS_EXTRA_NAME);

        String address = "";
        String body = "";

        for (int i = 0; i < smsExtra.length; ++i) {
            SmsMessage sms = SmsMessage.createFromPdu((byte[]) smsExtra[i]);
            body += sms.getMessageBody().toString();
            address = sms.getOriginatingAddress();
        }
      Toast.makeText(context, body,1000).show();
    }
```